# Can't remember the name of tactical board game

Tags: identify-this-game

I've played a board game on a digital platform (Tabletopia) 3 years ago, but can't remember the name. I have searched for it a long time but found nothing.

The game was a tactical board game in which each player had a squad of mechs / war vehicles. The map was divided in squares and each square had it's own terrain type with bonuses or disadvantages (the map was a photo realistic top view of the battlefield). For example forest hid your units and made it harder for them to be hit, high ground gave better accuracy, etc.
There were also some rules about zones which would be hit by meteorites, if I remember correctly. The game had miniatures for the units.

The game wasn't set in a well known universe like Warhammer 40k, Battletech or Mechwarriors. It was most likely made from scratch by the board game creators.

Comment: Any nearly indestructible super-tanks?  Thinking it might be a digital recreation/knockoff of Steve Jackson's *Ogre* mini-game.

Comment: Sounds more like a user created tabletop simulator game.

Comment: Farsight comes to mind, its around 5 years old, has minatures, hazards, is on Tabletopia, realistic background, uses squares and has mechs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first pass, I didn't see Farsight in the list of games on Tabletopia, but it [definitely exists](https://tabletopia.com/games/farsight).

Thanks to @Zibelas for the heads up.

This game matches several of your criteria.

- **3 years ago** -> Released in 2017.
- **tactical board game** -> The rule book flavor text says "*The survivors will not be the strongest warriors - they will be the greatest tacticians*."
- **each player had a squad of mechs / war vehicles** and **The game had miniatures for the units** -> No vehicles, but others are shown here:
  [image: minis]
- **The map was divided in squares** -> Yes, shown here:
  [image: terrain]
- **terrain type with bonuses or disadvantages ... forest hid your units and made it harder for them to be hit** -> Yes, on page 11 the rules mentions a forest rule "*attackers receive a -1 Attack penalty*."
- **high ground gave better accuracy** -> Yes, the rules attribute this rule "*gains +1 Attack / Defence strength. Artillery on a hill gains +1 range, allowing it to fire 4 spaces*" to hills.
- **hit by meteorites** -> Page 18 of the rules details a Meteors rule "*Roll a D10 to determine which square in each zone is hit*".
- **wasn't set in a well known universe** -> Yes, the rulebook has a bleak universe. "*In the future, there will be no countries - only corporations.
  Powerful Private Militias fight viciously over the Earth’s last remaining resources.*"